# How  "deliveryIntent" works in Android SMS framework?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, pdu

Android documentation for SMSManagers **sendTextMessage** function

```
public void sendTextMessage (String destinationAddress, String scAddress, String text,         
PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent)
```

**deliveryIntent**  *if not NULL this PendingIntent is broadcast when the message is delivered to the recipient. The raw pdu of the status report is in the extended data ("pdu")*

I could not understand if  deliveryIntent is fired when SMS is delivered to destinationAddress or scAddress and what is the meaning of "raw pdu of the status report is in the extended data ("pdu")" and how to get that report? .

I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is broadcast when message is delivered to `destinationAddress`.

The [PDU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_data_unit) may be extracted from the `Intent.getExtras().get("pdu")` when registered `BroadcastReceiver` receives the Intent broadcast you define with `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Context, int requestCode, Intent, int flags)`. For example:

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {      
    String DELIVERED = "DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    registerReceiver(
        new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                Object pdu = arg1.getExtras().get("pdu");
                ... //  Do something with pdu
            }

        },
        new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

    SmsManager smsMngr = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsMngr.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, deliveredPI);               
}
```

Then you need to parse extracted PDU, [SMSLib](http://smslib.org/doc/smslib/quickstart/) should be able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Just to build on a.ch's answer, heres how you can extract the delivery report from an intent:

```
 public static final SmsMessage[] getMessagesFromIntent(Intent intent) {
    Object[] messages = (Object[]) intent.getSerializableExtra("pdus");
    if (messages == null || messages.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    byte[][] pduObjs = new byte[messages.length][];

    for (int i = 0, len = messages.length; i < len; i++) {
        pduObjs[i] = (byte[]) messages[i];
    }

    byte[][] pdus = new byte[pduObjs.length][];
    SmsMessage[] msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
    for (int i = 0, count = pdus.length; i < count; i++) {
        pdus[i] = pduObjs[i];
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdus[i]);
    }

    return msgs;
}
```

Full credit to the great project at: http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/